# JavaScript block comments end prematurely due to RegExp syntax

Tags: javascript, regex, comments

This isn't a programming problem per se, more a question concerning the ECMAScript/JavaScript spec.

Consider the following JS.

```
let myexpr = /\*/; // Equivalent to `new RegExp("\\*")`
```

All well and good, a regex that matches the character `*`. But if we attempt a block comment

```
/*
let myexpr = /\*/; // Equivalent to `new RegExp("\\*")`
*/
```

we find that the escape character within the regex together with the end delimiter cause the block comment to end prematurely and the interpreter to attempt to execute `*/`, an obviously illegal expression. We can clearly fix this by abandoning the regex synax for the `RegExp` constructor, but that potentially requires even more escape characters and sacrifices readability.

I suppose my question is: why do the ES and/or JS specs allow the sequence `*/` to terminate a comment within a regex, but not, for instance, within a string?

Comment: a comment isn't code - therefore nothing in the comment is treated in any "special" way .. you just have to be careful with commented code - in fact, I'd never have actual code in a comment ever, that's not what comments are for

Comment: That should be an answer, no? ;)

Comment: Jaro's account is suspended so I'm adding the answer officially.

Answer (score 0):

All text inside a comment is not code. It is ALL skipped until `*/` is found.  Since you have `= /\*/;` within the text, the compiler will see `*/` and terminate the comment block earlier than you were expecting.

If you comment out a line instead you wouldn't have that problem:

```
// let myexpr = /\*/; // Equivalent to `new RegExp("\\*")`
```